# Is it possible for a delayed call to never get called in a thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, nsrunloop

Say you attach a timer to a runloop in a particular thread but the thread has exited before the timer gets triggered, causing the method to not be executed.  Is this scenario possible?

Comment: @MarcusAdams A timer will fire on the next pass through the event loop if the requested time has elapsed.  It'll never delay until next time through.

Comment: @bbum, I was thinking of repeating timers. Timer events can be skipped if they are too delayed. I deleted my comment. By "delayed call", we're probably not talking about repeating timers. :)

Comment: @MarcusAdams Ah.. OK.  My misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly this is possible, and it's easy enough to demonstrate.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define TIMER_INTERVAL 2.0

@interface Needle : NSObject

- (void)sew;
- (void)tick:(NSTimer *)tim;

@end

@implementation Needle
{
    NSTimer * tim;
}

- (void)sew
{
    @autoreleasepool{
        tim = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMER_INTERVAL
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(tick:)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:NO];

        while( ![[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled] ){
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"Let's get the bacon delivered!");
    [[NSThread currentThread] cancel];
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Needle * needle = [Needle new];
        NSThread * thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:needle
                                                    selector:@selector(sew)
                                                      object:nil];

        [thread start];
        // Change this to "+ 1" to see the timer fire.
        NSTimeInterval interval = TIMER_INTERVAL - 1;
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval]];
        [thread cancel];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you are on the main thread, there is no [`NSRunLoop`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference) keeping the thread alive and for the timers to attach to. You'll need to create one and let it run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. This happens quite easily, if there is a timer but the app quits "prematurely". In this case, the timer's fire date will be lost - even when the app gets restarted before the timer's fire date that has been set formerly.